# Как закодировать запрос к API Yobit.net в HMAC_SHA512

Tags: java

Пытаюсь получить данные методом **getInfo** вот из этого API https://yobit.net/ru/api/

> Каждый запрос должен пройти аутентификацию. Аутентификация
>   происходит способом отправки следующих HTTP-заголовков:
>
> Key - API-ключ, пример: FAF816D16FFDFBD1D46EEF5D5B10D8A2
>
> Sign - цифровая подпись, POST-параметры (?param0=val0 & ...& nonce=1)
>   подписанные секретным ключом с помощью HMAC-SHA512

Для Http запроса использую ApacheHttp.

Метод Post - запроса

```
public static String postApache(String url) {
            String dataFormServer = "";
            String dataToServer="?method=getInfo&nonce=20";
            String key = "xxx";
            String secretKey = "yyy";
            String signedData = calculateHMAC(dataToServer, secretKey);
            try {
                CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Key", key));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Sign",signedData));

                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));
                CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                if (entity != null) {
                    dataFormServer = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(entity.getContent(), "cp1251");
                }
                else System.out.println("Error");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return dataFormServer;
        }
```

HMAC генератор

```
private static String calculateHMAC(String data, String key) {
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), HMAC_SHA512);
        Mac mac = null;
        try {
            mac = Mac.getInstance(HMAC_SHA512);
            mac.init(secretKeySpec);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return toHexString(mac.doFinal(data.getBytes()));
    }
    private static  String toHexString(byte[] bytes) {
        final  char[] hexArray = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();
        char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
        for ( int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++ ) {
            int v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
            hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
            hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
        }
        return new String(hexChars);
    }
```

Сервер отвечает `{"success":0,"error":"invalid key, sign, method or nonce"}`
Ошибка может быть как в HMAC генераторе, так и в методе postApache. Не уверен ни в том ни в том.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В документации написано, что `Key / Sign` это заголовки, а вы отправляете их как POST-данные. `?method=getInfo&nonce=20` вот это вы вообще не отправляете нигде. В меня сработал такой код:

```
public static String postApache(String url) {
    String dataFormServer = "";
    String dataToServer = "method=getInfo&nonce=7";
    String key = "---";
    String secretKey = "---";
    String signedData = calculateHMAC(dataToServer, secretKey);
    try {
        CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        httpPost.addHeader("Key", key);
        httpPost.addHeader("Sign", signedData);

        httpPost.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(dataToServer.getBytes(), ContentType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED));

        CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if (entity != null) {
            dataFormServer = IOUtils.toString(entity.getContent(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        }
        else System.out.println("Error");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return dataFormServer;
}

private static String calculateHMAC(String data, String key) throws DecoderException {
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "HMACSHA512");
    Mac mac = null;
    try {
        mac = Mac.getInstance("HMACSHA512");
        mac.init(secretKeySpec);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    byte[] hmac = mac.doFinal(data.getBytes());
    return Hex.encodeHexString(hmac);
}
```

Comment: да, все верно. Спасибо!

Comment: Apache  запрос заработал. Но теперь сервер отвечат "Invalid sign". 
У Вас приходил правильный ответ от сервера или Вы не тестили? Может в методе calculateHMAC?

Comment: Да, все было хорошо. Я менял его пробовал разные варианты, но в итоге он у меня такой же как и у вас (вроде). Я добавил в сообщение на всякий случай.

Comment: Вот этот вот кусок 
---return Hex.encodeHexString(hmac);---
 из апачевской библиотеки, а у меня в исходном варианте использовалась стандартная java. Разобрался. Спасибо Вам!

Comment: Я не проверял ваш метод кодирования в Hex, не думал, что в нем может быть пробелма.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему, может кому пригодится.
Использовал бибилотеку **commons-codec**. 
Вот рабочий метод кодирования в sha512

```
private static String calculateHMAC(String data, String key) {
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), HMAC_SHA512);
        Mac mac = null;
        try {
            mac = Mac.getInstance(HMAC_SHA512);
            mac.init(secretKeySpec);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            return Hex.encodeHexString(mac.doFinal(data.getBytes("UTF-8")));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Тут смесь стандартной библиотеки java **javax.crypto** и апачевской **commons-codec**. Можно переписать на чистом Apache, получится меньше кода, но не стал заморачиваться.